# ActiveMQ change Web Console port

Tags: linux, jms, activemq-classic

I am currently working with ActiveMQ and JMS. I am facing the problem that I want to change the port of the ActiveMQ web console (running as localhost on Linux - ubuntu 22). Working on the default port (`8161`) is no problem, but when I change the port in the file `jetty.xml` the web console does not start (or starts briefly and then stops).

Here are the steps I did (installation path is: `/opt/apache-activemq-5.17.1/`)

```
$ cd opt/apache-activemq-5.17.1/conf
$ sudo nano jetty.xml
```

Change port from `8161` to `61616` in `jetty.xml`:

```xml
<bean id="jettyPort" class="org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsolePort" init-method="init-method="start">
    <!-- the default port number for the web console -->
    <property name="host" value="127.0.0.1"/>
    <!--property name="port" value="8161"/>-->
    <property name="port" value=61616">
</bean>
```

After saving and returning I start ActiveMQ:

```
$ cd /opt/apache-activemq-5.17.1/bin/linux-x86-64
$ ls -l
total 152
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  15456 Mai 22 10:07 activemq
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  15248 Mai 22 10:07 libwrapper.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 111027 Mai 22 10:07 wrapper
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6730 Mai 22 10:07 wrapper.conf
$ sudo ./activemq start
Starting ActiveMQ Broker...
# Checking the status 
$ sudo ./activemq status
ActiveMQ Broker is running (26867).
# Checking the status again (about 2-5 seconds execution last command)
$ sudo ./activemq status
ActiveMQ Broker is not running.
```

Edit/Solution:

The server did not start because OpenWire is already listening on port `61616`. I have restored the default configurations. If you work with JMS, it is simply possible to access ActiveMQ on the default port `8161` via the browser and send messages with `tcp://localhost:61616` in Java. Thanks to the user justin-bertram!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default ActiveMQ listens on port `61616` for connections from OpenWire clients. See this in `activemq.xml`:

```xml
<transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

Therefore, if you change Jetty to also listen on port `61616` either Jetty or ActiveMQ itself will fail to start since only one service can be bound to any specific port at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and pointing out that OpenWire is listening on port `61616`. I was able to get it to work.